# get inactive devices of all time from APNs feedback

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, feedback

when i try and get the inactive device tokens from the feedback service i get the tokens but after that the service doesn't return anything.
is there any way for me to get all the tokens from all time?

i'm using PHP to get the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Server will return all inactive tokens since last time you asked for feedback. The way to quick test is,

1. Run feedback service once
2. Delete the app from phone
3. Again run the feedback service, you should get one inactive token.

Just make sure feedback service address is correct.

Comment: thank you for the reply. but my question is whether or not i can get all the inactive tokens from the beginning of the log and not just the new inactive ones since i checked?

Comment: I already went that path, currently there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not way to get the inactive tokens again once the APNS feedback is queried. Since there are no parameter available the service is provided as is:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3